# java- Big O Notations

Tags: algorithm, big-o

So, I have tried to solve some big o questions and I had some troubles with some of them. I don't quite understand them.
like for eg the dominant term of `10MlogM + (N/2) log (N/2) + N/4`
and   `M log (N) + M log (M )`. I have trouble understanding big o expressions with 'log' in them. Any help would be appreciated and thanks in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a plain English explanation of "Big O" notation?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/487258/what-is-a-plain-english-explanation-of-big-o-notation)

Comment: What are `M` and `N`? Typically, such notation is conventional for graph problems, where `N` and `M` represent the number of vertices and edges, respectively. Technically, `M = O(N^2)`, and the entire thing could be written in terms of `N` alone, but using a separate variable `M`  lets you emphasize the part that depends on how dense or sparse the graph is. For example, in a sparse graph, `M log (N) + M log M` might be `N log N`, while in a dense graph it would be closer to `N^2 log N`.

Comment: This almost feels like it should be ported to a sister site.

Answer (score 0):

> I have trouble understanding big o expressions with 'log' in them

It's quite easy to understand **Big-O** of *`log`* (or any function) if we draw its graph:

[image]

Now since you are facing an equation having multiple terms (and one of them is *`log`*), so maybe it would confuse you out. If we plot first term (*I assume its `NlogN` and discard the constant (10)*):

[image]

Similarly for other term (*`N/2 * log(N/2)`*):

[image]

I am sure you will already know, but this graph easily demonstrates that only major term (*`N logN`*) defines the **Big O** (*as its just to show the upper bound of function*) as I plot the graph of whole function:

[image]

**What does N log N mean**

This [link](https://www.codeproject.com/questions/500926/whatplusisplusnpluslogplusnplusmeanspluspracticall) provides very good explanation with this example:

> O(n log n): There was a mix-up at the printer's office, and our phone book had all its pages inserted in a random order. Fix the ordering so that it's correct by looking at the first name on each page and then putting that page in the appropriate spot in a new, empty phone book.
>
> For the below examples, we're now at the printer's office. Phone books
>   are waiting to be mailed to each resident or business, and there's a
>   sticker on each phone book identifying where it should be mailed to.
>   Every person or business gets one phone book.
>
> O(n log n): We want to personalize the phone book, so we're going to
>   find each person or business's name in their designated copy, then
>   circle their name in the book and write a short thank-you note for
>   their patronage.